# Add command-line arguments to visual Studio Project in TeamCity

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity, command-line-arguments

If I run a c++ project/solution, in Visual Studio, with a command line option "--xx", how can I do the exact same thing from TeamCity ?

I have searched and have been unable to find any option.

The one thing that looks like "Command line parameters" is actually designated for MSBuild.

I have to run the solution - and not just the executable generated by the solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Visual Studio build is executed using MSBuild on the server, the name may be a little confusing, but the parameters should function in the same way using that MSBuild parameter box as passing them to visual studio would be.

if there are issues getting this to work using that parameters box, we will need some more information about the commands you need to run and the behaviour you need.

**Edit following questioner's comment**

The problem in actuality here is that Visual Studio builds don't *really* exist in TeamCity, visual studio build is actually just going to run MsBuild against your visual studio solution, which, in terms of Google Test, is sufficiently different to cause your problems.

To resolve this, you are probably going to have to change your build runner to just be an MsBuild script which builds your solution and runs the Google tests. thankfully, the internet provides:

http://code.google.com/p/msbuildteamcitytasks/wiki/RunGoogleTests

The above is some MsBuild tasks which claim to integrate GoogleTest results completely with TeamCity, doing all the leg work for you in that regard. The result of this is that you only need a very brief build script calling MsBuild on your solution, followed by calling that MsBuild Task as required. I cant confirm how well they work or how easy they are to set up as I haven't used them, but the documentation on the page implies it should be reasonably easy to put together.

below is a snippet of MsBuild that will build your solution(s)

```
<MSBuild Projects="@(BuildProjects)" Targets="Rebuild" BuildInParallel="true" Properties="Configuration=Debug;Platform=$(Platform)">
  <Output ItemName="DebugOutputs" TaskParameter="TargetOutputs"/>
</MSBuild>
```

where each $() variable is a system property in your TeamCity configuration @(BuildProjects) is a list of solutions generated using this:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <BuildProjects Include="$(WorkingArea)\**\*.sln" />
</ItemGroup>
```

you can of course hard code any and all of these variables, or change parameters as required, but this example will give you some freedom to reuse the script on other projects (its not a full script, there's some extra structure stuff to go around the outside).

you can of course build in further functionality to the script as required, or leave it as simple as possible to make it easy to understand.

there is further documentation on MsBuild scripts are available from these locations:
http://www.universalthread.com/ViewPageArticle.aspx?ID=61
http://codingcockerel.co.uk/2008/04/15/automating-the-build-with-msbuild/
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12985/Practical-NET2-and-C-2-An-introduction-to-MSBuild

I'm sure there's plenty more out there if you need it.

Comment: The project I am building is a google test project that I would like to be able to build and generate xml reports during build - so I have to be able to run it with option "--gtest_output=xml" at least (best, --gtest_output="xml:file.xml"). When I try to run in TeamCity, and put this option in the parameters box, I get error "MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch."

Comment: I have updated my answer to make it more informative on your given situation, it may now be more help to you in resolving your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Well, In **TeamCity** (*I am using version 6.5.x*), When you add a new Build Step, select the Build runner as **Visual Studio (sln)** or **Visual Studio 2003** as per your requirement and there you'll get the option to pass command line parameters.

What Version of TeamCity do you use?

Comment: If you want to paas msbuild command line parameters, have you tried passing like this: `/p:parameter=value` ? It's actually confusing what exactly you are trying to paas? can you please edit the question and give some example/reference?